# How to align views in linear layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I want align Horizontally in linear layout. So I use weight attribute for align views. But after setting value some values are not getting set properly.

Below is layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingStart="5dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingEnd="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingStockName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:text="Bharati Airtel Ltd."
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingSectorName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Telecommunication - service provider"
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingSchemeWeight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:text="15.00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Output looks like [image: image for reference]
I want them align properly like headings.

Comment: If you want all with equal space then just use _android:gravity="center"_ for all _AppCompatTextView_

Comment: can u show what u have done for heading layout

Comment: @Jeeva I have used same layout for headings as well.

Comment: Use recycler if you have more items to show

Comment: @shohruhMaxmudov using Recycler view to show data below headings.

Comment: yes @PallaviTapkir

Answer (score 3):

you should add `"weightSum = 2.7"` in your `linearLayout`. so that all of your views in a layout are balanced.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:weightSum="2.7"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingStart="5dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingEnd="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingStockName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:text="Bharati Airtel Ltd."
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingSectorName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Telecommunication - service provider"
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/topHoldingSchemeWeight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:text="15.00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: I already tried that. It still not align views properly.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir post your complete layout.

Comment: The posted one is complete only the missing line is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: this is your code for one line, I am talking about the whole code. Because clearly you have made separate layouts for all three rows that's why they are not aligning and they won't. I am talking with reference to the image you posted.

Comment: No I am using recycler view. This is the layout row I am using in adapter class.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir It's working fine on my side. Can you post your @style/RegularGreyText too?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. It not related to layout, while inflating layout in adapter class I am passing root value as null, passing ViewGroup resolved the issue.

Comment: it's ok happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use weight property to device view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Stock Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sector"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tata Chemical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Chemical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="15%"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `android:weightSum="2.7"` to your parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="2.7"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingStockName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="Bharati Airtel Ltd."
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingSectorName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Telecommunication - service provider"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingSchemeWeight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="15.00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

**Replace your code with following xml code..**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingStockName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bharati Airtel Ltd."
        android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingSectorName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Telecommunication - service provider"
        android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/topHoldingSchemeWeight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="15.00"
        android:textAppearance="@style/RegularGreyText"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]